# Getting error after upgrading Android Gradle Plugin to 8.2.0: Gradle DSL method not found: 'archivesBaseName()'

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, apk

After I updated Android Gradle Plugin from version 8.1.4 to 8.2.0 I am getting this error:

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'archivesBaseName()'
```

I use this method for specifying the output apk filename, like this:

```
archivesBaseName "${rootProject.name.replaceAll(" ", "")}-v${versionName}"
```

Since it seems like this function is removed from AGP now, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by changing it to this:

```
setProperty("archivesBaseName", "${rootProject.name.replaceAll(" ", "")}-v${versionName}")
```